# Custom Overlay with FlashLite using just Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, zxing

I'm doing a Xamarin Forms App for Android with a QRcode scanner.
I'm using ZXing library and all codes that I finded online are using XAML, but i what to use just C#.

What I need is a CustomOverlay with a Flashlite button without using XAML.

Something like ZxingOverlayView with a flashlite button.

Thank's for help and sorry for my bad English.